# The callback in S3.putObject().on('httpUploadProgress', callback) doesn't update a React state array correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3

[Github repo](https://github.com/BitterDone/ReactAwsS3UploadProgress)

My desired goal is a state array that's updated in real-time with the upload progress of multiple file.

Each callback is able to update the % progress for its file at the correct index in the state array `uploadProg`, but it's like they can't see the updated `uploadProg` that result from other callbacks.

In the image below, the first `> (3) [0,0,0]` is logging `uploadProg` before updating, the second is logging `newUploadProg` after updating.

What am I missing here? Is this a misunderstanding of closures in Javascript?

Thank you for any insights!

[image: uploadProg state array]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

function App() {
  const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState({})
  const [uploadProg, setUploadProg] = useState([])

  var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    apiVersion: '2012-10-17',
    accessKeyId: 'accessKeyId',
    secretAccessKey: 'secretAccessKey',
  });

   const handleFile = event => {
      setSelectedFiles(event?.target?.files)
      setUploadProg(new Array(Object.keys(event?.target?.files).length).fill(0))
   }

   const upload = event => {
     Object.keys(selectedFiles).forEach((key, index) => {
      console.log(key)
      console.log(selectedFiles[key])
      var params = {
        Body: selectedFiles[key], 
        Bucket: "uploadprogress", 
        Key: `exampleobject${index}`, 
       };

       s3.putObject(params)
        .on('httpUploadProgress', (progressEvent, response) => {
          const newUploadProg = [...uploadProg]
          const percent = parseInt(100*progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total)
          newUploadProg[index] = percent
          console.log(uploadProg)
          console.log(newUploadProg)
          console.log('______________')
          setUploadProg(newUploadProg)
        })
        .send((err, data) => {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
          else     console.log(data);
         })
    })  
   }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <input type="file" name="file" onChange={handleFile} multiple/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onClick={upload}>Upload</button>
        {uploadProg.map(percent => (<div style={{
          margin: 5,
          width: 100,
          height: 10,
          backgroundColor: 'green'
        }}>
          <div style={{
            height: 8,
            width: percent,
            backgroundColor: 'yellow',
          }}>
          </div>
        </div>))}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Shoutout to u/ScottRatigan on r/reactjs:](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/fu87ap/the_callback_in_s3putobjectonhttpuploadprogress/fmbftd8)

> What am I missing here? Is this a misunderstanding of closures in Javascript?
>
> Sort of, yes.
>
> When multiple events fire quickly and update the same object, they're
>   being called with the same initial value. So if event 1 updates one
>   index in the array, and event 2 updates another one, the second update
>   can "wipe out" the first update. But since this is a common issue,
>   there is a good solution as well.
>
> When you call the state update function returned from useState (
>   setUploadProg in this case), you can pass it either a value, or a
>   function to update the value based on the previous value. (This is the
>   same as a traditional setState call in a class-based React component.
>
> I'll give you an example with two versions of essentially the same
>   function:
>
> ```
> import React, { useState } from 'react'
>
> export default function Broken() {
>   const [arr, setArr] = useState([0, 0]);
>
>   const fn = () => {
>     const newArr = [...arr];
>     newArr[0] = 1;
>     setArr(newArr);
>   }
>
>   const fn2 = () => {
>     const newArr = [...arr];
>     newArr[1] = 2;
>     setArr(newArr);
>   }
>
>   return (
>     <div>
>       <button type="button" onClick={() => {
>         fn();
>         fn2();
>       }}>Button</button>
>     </div>
>   )
> }
> ```
>
> The above code block exhibits a simple version of the bug you
>   describe. Alternate version is here:
>
> ```
> import React, { useState } from 'react'
>
> export default function Works() {
>   const [arr, setArr] = useState([0, 0]);
>
>   const fn = () => {
>     setArr(arr => {
>       arr[0] = 1;
>       return arr;
>     });
>   }
>
>   const fn2 = () => {
>     setArr(arr => {
>       arr[1] = 2;
>       return arr;
>     });
>   }
>
>   return (
>     <div>
>       <button type="button" onClick={() => {
>         fn();
>         fn2();
>       }}>Button</button>
>     </div>
>   )
> }
> ```
>
> This one works.